# What are the configuration differences between Apache (httpd-2.2.3-22.el5.centos) in CentOS 5 vs Apache (httpd-2.2.15-39.el6) in CentOS 6?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, centos6, migration, centos5

I understand that the later version addresses security vulnerabilities:

http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_22.html

Supposedly, http://httpd.apache.org/download.html has a full list of changes at http://httpd.apache.org/[preferred]/httpd/CHANGES_2.2, but apache.org no longer seems to have a CHANGES_2.2 file available.

Anyway, without poring over the release notes, has anyone dealt with this sort of upgrade before to know what configuration differences affect the change between CentOS httpd version 2.2.3-22.el5.centos and CentOS httpd version 2.2.15-39.el6?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the results for [a search for inurl:"httpd/CHANGES_2.2"](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:%22httpd%2FCHANGES_2.2%22) look like CHANGES_2.2 for the Apache web server made its way to some other sites:

http://supergsego.com/apache/httpd/CHANGES_2.2

It looks like most of these changes fix bugs, add new directives, or remove security problems.

The changes that are not bugfixes or security patches from Apache (httpd-2.2.3-22.el5.centos) in CentOS 5 to Apache (httpd-2.2.15-39.el6) in CentOS 6 that seem to actually require attention to configuration from the changes from version to version follow:

```
  *) mod_proxy: Complete ProxyPassReverse to handle balancer URL's.  Given;
   BalancerMember balancer://alias http://example.com/foo
   ProxyPassReverse /bash balancer://alias/bar
     backend url http://example.com/foo/bar/that is now translated /bash/that
     [William Rowe]

  *) core/utils: Enhance ap_escape_html API to support escaping non-ASCII
     chars [Nick Kew]

  *) Output -M and -S dumps (modules and vhosts) to stdout instead of stderr.
     PR 42571 and PR 44266 (dup).  [Dan Poirier <poirier pobox.com>]

  *) Linux 2.0: remove support for threaded MPM's due to linuxthreads use
     of SIGUSR1 clashing with graceful restart signal. [Colm MacCarthaigh]

  *) Change the default (when not present in the config file) setting
     for UseCanonicalName to Off.
     [Joshua Slive]

  *) mod_userdir: The module no longer does any remapping unless the
     UserDir directive is present in the config file.
     [Joshua Slive]

2.1.4

  *) Massively simplify the distributed httpd.conf by removing
     many features and many directives that are at their default
     setting.  Add a selection of example config excerpts for adding
     extra features in the conf/extra/ directory.  Install the
     distributed config and the extra config examples in the
     conf/original/ directory during make install.
     [Joshua Slive, Justin Erenkrantz]
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to hijack your post, but I'd like to ask, what's the difference between the original and extra file? they both seem to contain httpd-ssl file. If I wish to install the certificate? How should I configure it/Which should I configure?